# How to autofill billing information?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, css, ruby-on-rails-4

So, I have an app that has user subscriptions. In my case the user is associated with an organization and is required to fill in the organization address. There's also the billing information section with a checkbox that says "Check if same name and organization address". When this checkbox is clicked I'd like to port over and autofill all of the address details i.e. state, country etc... from Organization address.

How might I do this? I've looked into it and coudn't find a simple implementation.

See the billing_information checkbox code below:

```
 <div class="checkbox click">
      <input id="check1" type="checkbox" value="check1" name="check">
      <label for="check1" style="color:#fff !important;" class="checkbox_label"> Check if same name and organization address</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <input type="text" class="form-control-input address" placeholder="Address">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <input type="text" class="form-control-input city" placeholder="City">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6">
          <input type="text" class="form-control-input state" placeholder="State/Province/Region">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6">
          <input type="text" class="form-control-input zip_code" placeholder="Zip/Postal Code">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6" style="color:#fff; font-size:20px;">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg continue-button">Update</button>
          or <a href="#" class="cancel-t" data-dismiss='modal'>Cancel</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: maybe it has sth to do with http://schema.org/address. I think those schemas are browser specific, in a sense that you have to use them once until the browser remembers the inputted information such as address. The next time you try to enter identical data, then the browser suggests that if you want to use address details that you have used previously. Alternative, your app can always save some data into the browser memory (session or cookie for example) and use at a later time.

Comment: More info on Schemas and Microdata: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/using-microdata-to-markup-structured-data